# How to make 2 for loop for these function in one

Tags: python, django

i have some problem how to merge 2 for loop in one, the function like this :

```
for profile in profileContent['profiles']:
    profileName = profile['profileName']
for data_setting in profileContent['datasettings']:
    dataSettingName = data_setting['dataSettingName']
```

i have merge 2 for loop in one like this but still wrong, any idea for fix this?

```
for profile,data_setting in profileContent['profiles']:
    profileName = profile['profileName']
    dataSettingName = data_setting['dataSettingName']`
```

Comment: use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

Comment: Please have a look at the edited question layout and verify that this is exactly how your code looks like.

Comment: Surely each variable will end up with the last item in the items. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `zip()` function after the `in` in your loop like this:

```
for profile, data_setting in zip(profileContent['profiles'],profileContent['datasettings']):
    profileName = profile['profileName']
    dataSettingName = data_setting['dataSettingName']
```

Answer (score 1):

if len(profileContent['profiles']) equal to len(profileContent['datasettings']):

```
zz = zip(profileContent['profiles'], profileContent['datasettings']) 
ll = [x['profileName'], y['dataSettingName'] for x, y in zz]
```

else:

```
from itertools import product
pp= product(profileContent['profiles'], profileContent['datasettings']) 
ll = [x['profileName'], y['dataSettingName'] for x, y in pp]
```